# Expression Register - Power, Root & Mod

Tags: register, expression-register

##### Foreword

In case you don't know, you can evaluate math expressions in **vim/neovim** with this command:

`While in INSERT mode, press CTRL+R, then =`. Example: `=2+2` inserts 4 into your buffer.

---

## Question

Is there a way to evaluate **power**, **root** and **modulo** of numbers inside the **expression register**?

I want for example:

- `=2^16`
- `=2**16`
- `=10 mod 3`
- `=10 % 3`

I only get this **Error**:
`E15: Invalid expression: 2^16`

---

##### Afterword

I know that you can do something like `:echo pow(2, 16)`, but I want to do it in the expression register.

I have read the `:help i_CTRL-R` page and the `:help expression` page, and could not find anything about this. Maybe I missed something?

---

---

Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions such as [`pow()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#pow%28%29) from the expression register.

Just enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `=pow(2, 16)`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will enter `65536.0` which is the result of 2 to the power 16.

Similarly, you can use [`fmod()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#fmod%28%29) for the modulus operator.

In your example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `=fmod(10, 3)`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will enter `1.0` which is the modulus of 10 by 3.

Note that both of these operations return floats, so you might want to use [`float2nr()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#float2nr%28%29) to convert those to integers: `=float2nr(pow(2, 16))` and `=float2nr(fmod(10, 3))`.

You can also use ["method syntax"](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#method) or the arrow operator `->` to call these functions in a row, which is quite convenient for the conversion for float, for example `=pow(2, 16)->float2nr()`. Or you can even go all the way, with `=2->pow(16)->float2nr()`.

In short, the expression register can take any kinds of expressions. Function calls are expressions like any others, so you can just use them as normal in the expressions you pass the `=` register.